# Calculate days stay based on checkin to checkout when check out time is at 12.00 noon

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

```
<?php
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM roombooking where enddate>='$today'" ;

    $result1 = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result1->num_rows > 0){
    echo"
    <div class=table-responsive border >
      <table class=table>
        <tr>

        <th>Room Type</th>
        <th>Room Number</th>
        <th> Status </th>
        <th> Check-in date </th>
        <th> Check-Out date  </th>
        <th>Stay Time</th>
        <th colspan='2'>Action </th>
        </tr>";
        // output data of each row

        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) 
        { echo "<tr>
               <td>".$row["roomtype"]."</td>
               <td>".$row["roomnumber"]."</td>
               <td>".$row["bkg_status"]."</td>
               <td>".$d1=$row["bkg_clientintime"]."</td>
               <td>".$d2=$row["bkg_clientouttime"]."</td>


               </tr>";
            }
     echo "</table></div>";
    }else { echo "<br>"."<div class='alert alert-info col col-md-6 col-md-offset-2'> SORRY NO CHEK OUT FOUND FOR TODAY 

    </div> ";}
?>
//here from $d1 which is booking check-in-date and $d2 which is check-out-date 
HELP REQUIRED // important checkout date time is 12.00 noon 
HELP REQUIRED 2// FINDING TOTAL Number of days stay 

any suggestion are greatly appreciated 
tried here date_diff / it again gives hours or days but have to find based on
12.00 noon important checkout otherwise new day will be added  how to achieve this part  kindly guide
```

Comment: after $d2 i want to echo total number of days  stay by guest  how to calculcate that ??  if check out time is twelve noon important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here easiest way is calculate date different on mysql

```
SELECT *,
  DATE_DIFF(DATE(bkg_clientintime), DATE(bkg_clientouttime)) AS no_days
FROM roombooking
```

Comment: thanks Mr Dilipen D ..  but how to check date diff  based on check out is at 12.00 noon  not on date change .. it may so happen that  the client may checkin 5 hrs before checkout time  that is 12.00 noon  thus he will pay for complete days here itself .. then we need to calculate remaining time based on  different remaining dates

Comment: I think first you want to find total different hours and convert it to days  ````SELECT CEIL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2009-05-18 11:45:42','2009-05-20 15:16:39')/24) AS no_days;```

Comment: hi the datediff helped to fetch the data and also the difference of days between in and out but if the guest walks in at 5 am his checkout time is 12.00 noon,  so when guest leave on 1 am in night it will show only 1 day where as it should show like 2 days like from 5am till 12.00 noon =1 day and from 12.00 noon till 1am 1 day thus 2 days stay how to achieve this   thanks a ton dilipen D a alot ahead  Ur help is valuable and very much helpfull  // Sorry by mistake i downvoted, twice but when i understood only select tick for right answer i did it and to control the damage i uptick twice

Comment: Use ROUND method insted of CEIL. It will return what your expecting answer

Comment: hi Dilipen D thank you  for your valuable comment  i tried both function ROUND AND CEIL BUT not working as expected like  ''SELECT CEIL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2009-05-18 1:30:00','2009-05-18 15:16:39')/24) AS no_days ''  & '' SELECT ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2009-05-18 1:30:00','2009-05-18 15:16:39')/24) AS no_days'' result is 01 days but thats  wrong as check out time is 12.00 noon not midnignt

Comment: if  in this case :this is check in time   2009-05-18 1:30:00', at night then from 1.30 AM midnight till 12.00 noon it will be billed as 1 days stay ..  as the client is chekingout  at     '2009-05-18 15:16:39 (after 12.00 noon )  it is same date but will be calculated as 2 days stay .. that is where i am stuck  any help will be highly appreciated .. thanks in adv

Comment: is there any way to calculate time difference from 12.00 noon to 12.00 ??